# Desabilitar Fabric Answer

Tags: android, fabrio.io

Eu tenho o [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary) adicionado em meu app. Hoje por curiosidade eu habilitei o [Answer](https://fabric.io/kits/android/answers/summary) no dashboard do site do [Fabric.io](https://fabric.io/).

Gostaria de desabilitá-lo é possível?

Procurei por várias opções no dashboard do site, mas não encontrei nenhuma que faça isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente não existe uma forma de você desabilitar completamente o `Answers`, baseado [nesta discussão](https://twittercommunity.com/t/can-i-disable-answers-on-my-app-whilst-leaving-crash-reporting-enabled/55249/7) na comunidade do *Twitter*.

Note que, como mencionado pelo membro da *staff*, agora o Fabric possui dois modos separados de instalação: um para o **Crashlytics** e outro para o **Answers**. Você pode tentar fazer uma nova instalação para o mesmo aplicativo e só habilitar o *Crashlytics*.

Caso contrário, como na conclusão desta discussão acima, foi solicitado o "bundle id/package name" para o usuário e então parece que foi excluído manualmente por um membro da equipe.

Comment: Depois que eu postei a pergunta aqui, eu pesquisei mais um pouco e encontrei essa mesma discussão. Acho que seria legal eles disponibilizarem uma forma de desabilitar o serviço de forma mais simples. Obrigado pela ajuda!!!